# Defining hash function as part of a struct

Tags: c++

I know that it's possible to define a hash function for a `struct X` by defining a separate hash function struct:

```
struct hash_X {
    size_t operator()(const X &x) const {}
    bool operator()(const X &a, const X &b) const {}
};
int main() {
    unordered_set<X, hash_X, hash_X> s;
}
```

But I'm looking for something like `operator<`, which can be attached to `struct X` itself, e.g. with `set`:

```
struct X {
    bool operator<(const X &other) const {}
};
int main() {
    set<X> s;
}
```

The end goal is something like:

```
struct X {
    size_t operator()(void) const {}
    bool operator()(const X &other) const {}
};

int main() {
    unordered_set<X> s;
}
```

Is this possible in C++?

Comment: There's no hash operator, but why not just define a method? Name it `hash` or something.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to create an `unordered_set<X>` without having to define an additional struct for the hash function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::unordered_set` is defined within `std` namespace. And it uses `std::hash` structures to hash many different types. If you want to be able to use `std::unordered_set<X>` (without adding much info to the declaration), you must create another overload of the `std::hash` template, so as to make it *hash* your structure.

You should be able to get it working by doing the following:

```
# include <unordered_set>
struct X {
    size_t operator()(void) const {}
    bool operator()(const X &other) const {}
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<X> {
        inline size_t operator()(const X& x) const {
            // size_t value = your hash computations over x
            return value;
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<X> s;
}
```

---

Andalso, you must provide either an overload to `std::equal_to`, or a comparison operator (`operator==()`) for your structure. You should add one of the following:

```
struct X {
    ...
    inline bool operator==(const X& other) const {
        // bool comparison = result of comparing 'this' to 'other'
        return comparison;
    }

};
```

Or:

```
template <>
struct equal_to<X> {
    inline bool operator()(const X& a, const X& b) const {
        // bool comparison = result of comparing 'a' to 'b'
        return comparison;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I also have to define std::equal_to<X> to insert X instances into the set?

Comment: @icedtrees Duly noted! I had not ran the code, and therefore had not tried to perform any insertion. Without the comparison operator (or the `std::equal_to` template overload) you cannot perform insertions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no hash operator, but you could hide the `hash` struct inside of your `X`:

```
struct X
{
    std::string name;

    struct hash
    {
        auto operator()( const X& x ) const
        { return std::hash< std::string >()( x.name ); }
    };
};
```

You could even make it a friend and make `name` private, etc.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02e50913bac2e270)

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace hashing {
  template<class T>
  std::size_t hash(T const&t)->
  std::result_of_t<std::hash<T>(T const&)>
  {
    return std::hash<T>{}(t);
  }
  struch hasher {
    template<class T>
    std::size_t operator()(T const&t)const{
      return hash(t);
    }
  };
}
```

the above is some boilerplate that sets up an adl-based `hash` system.

```
template<class T>
using un_set=std::unordered_set<T,hashing::hasher>;
template<class K, class V>
using un_map=std::unordered_map<K,V,hashing::hasher>;
```

now creates two container aliases where you do not have to specify the hasher.

To add a new hashable:

```
struct Foo {
  std::string s;
  friend size_t hash(Foo const&f){
    return hashing::hasher{}(s);
  }
};
```

and `Foo` works in `un_set` and `un_map`.

I would add support for `std` containers and tuples into `hashing` namespace (override the function `hash` for them), and magically those will work too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to consider a more general hash class.  You could define for this class all the common hash manipulation operations that you could need:

```
struct ghash {
     // all the values and operations you need here 
};
```

Then in any class where you want to compute a hash, you could define a conversion operator

```
struct X { 
    operator ghash () {  // conversion operator 
        ghash rh; 
        // compute the hash
        return rh; 
    }
};
```

You can then easily calculate the hash:

```
 X x; 
 ghash hx = x;   // convert x to a hash 
 hx = (ghash)x;  // or if you prefer to make it visible
```

This will make it easier to extend the use of your hash structure without  reinventing the common ground for any other struct X, Y,Z that may need a hash in the future.

[Live demo here](http://ideone.com/3xDEZL)